# Jest fails for external npm packages

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I'm using jest for the first time with React, This time I'm using it with React Native project. and it working perfect with below code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';


export default class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Login Page</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

But after added a Button from my component library, jest fail the test.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

import { Button } from 'tc-components';    

export default class Login extends Component {
   render() {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>Login Page</Text>
          <View>
            <Button onPress={this.loginHandler.bind(this)}>Log in</Button>
          </View>
        </View>
      )
   }
}
```

error message

```
- SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
        at transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/transform.js:306:10)
        at Object.<anonymous> (app/scenes/Activity.js:2:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/Activity-test.js:3:15)
1 test suite failed, 0 tests passed (0 total in 1 test suite, run time 1.261s)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to manually mock `tc-component` in your test file

```
jest.mock('tc-component', () => {
  const React = require('react');
  const TC = {}

  const createComponent = (type) => {
    return React.createClass({
      displayName: type,
      propTypes: {
        children: React.PropTypes.node
      },
      render() {
        return <div {...this.props}>{this.props.children}</div>;
      }
    });
  };

  TC.Button = createComponent("Button");

  return TC;
});

import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';

import Activity from '../scenes/Activity';

// Note: test renderer must be required after react-native.
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

describe('Activity', () => {

  it('renders correctly', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(
      <Activity />
    ).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

});
```